# How to enable dynamic email development in gmail?

Tags: gmail, amp-email

Using this [playground](https://amp.gmail.dev/playground/), I sent `AMP4EMAIL` markup to my `gmail` account.

I got this generated message: 
This is the HTML content.

```
To see dynamic emails sent from amp@gmail.dev in Gmail, whitelist 
amp@gmail.dev in Gmail Settings > General > Dynamic email > Dynamic email 
development.
```

However I cannot find these setting in gmail.
How do I enable this setting?

Answer (score 2):

You have to follow this steps:

1. Switch to an administrator account. This will open the Google Admin console.
2. From the Admin console Home page, go to **Company profile > Profile**.
3. Scroll to New products.
4. Select an option:

   - **Manual**: New services are off until you turn them on yourself.
     [Manual release](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rr5Vi.png)
5. At the bottom, click Save.

This change might take up to 24 hours to take effect.

After this steps, go to Admin console  and navigate yo **Apps > G Suite > Settings for Gmail > User Settings**. Here they will be able to select the option to [Enable dynamic email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IbUkp.png)

Finally you will see the option **Dynamic email 
development** on your Gmail settings.

source: https://support.google.com/a/answer/82691?hl=en

Comment: Above mentioned steps are for organisation accounts using G-Suite. How to enable these settings for free gmail users where there is no administrator account?

Comment: Sure, for a normal gmail, Google is giving some problems. Hard refresh of Gmail made that configuration was shown to me.